# What if your opinion conflicts with site audits?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

Recently I found a question [How to search a string with spaces and special characters in vi editor [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036575/how-to-search-a-string-with-spaces-and-special-characters-in-vi-editor) which was given to me as an audit for re-open votes. I think this is a genuine question as it is about a specific problem in a  programming tool and the user has shown effort in solving the problem. I voted to re-open and the site says it was an audit and I was wrong.

What to do in such a situation? I know making a wrong vote is not a big problem, but still want to know the opinion of others too.

Comment: Well, it's certainly about a specific problem, and the user has shown effort, but to me at least (admittedly with no particular experience in vim) it's ... "unclear" what, precisely, the specific problem **is**. Hence the close, I'd assume.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree, it will be totally unclear if you don't know vim. Isn't it better to leave the question alone if you don't know the subject.

Comment: Often; not always, though. I neither voted nor flagged, and I'm not sure I would have, but that would probably be why.

Comment: The right thing to do when you disagree with an audit is to open the post and take the proper action, if any.  That will also prevent the audit from reappearing to other users.  You can ask a question here on meta if you're unsure what the proper action is, or if you still think complaining about audits will change anything.

Comment: I edited this question a little to hopefully make the problem statement clearer and remove noise.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Note that the *lack* of audit complaints has been used on at least one occasion to justify not investigating any possible improvements to audits.

Comment: IMO: VI is not really a development tool even though developers choose to do code editing with it, and the question being asked is not development related. Its off-topic. If questions about VI usage become on-topic then SO becomes product support for any and all text editor in the world.

Comment: There's a [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) where such questions might belong.

Comment: The review audit process seems to be entirely arbitrary. Unless you treat everyone as if they should know all the arcane minutia of StackOverflow rather than having a genuine issue to solve, you will consistently fail audits.